# python tarfile to ignore directory structure while creating tarball

Tags: python

I am having a direcotry structure as :

```
D:\testfolder\folder_to_tar:
                |---folder1
                      |--- file1.txt
                |---folder2
                      |--- file2.txt
                |---file3.txt
```

I want to create a tarball using Python at the same directory level. However, I am observing that in the tarball python is including the parent directory as well i.e. `testfolder` in my example.

```
Expected Output :
D:\testfolder:
        |---folder_to_tar.tar
                |---folder_to_tar
                        |--folder1
                            .....

Actual Output :
D:\testfolder:
        |---folder_to_tar.tar
                |---testfolder
                       |---folder_to_tar
                                |--folder1
                                       .....
```

Code :

```
import tarfile

tarname = "D:\\testfolder\\folder_to_tar"
tarfile1 = "D:\\testfolder\\folder_to_tar.tar"

tarout = tarfile.open(tarfile1,mode="w")

try:
    tarout.add(tarname,arcname=tarname)     
finally:
    tarout.close()
```

Can some one please help me on how to achieve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try replacing the tarout.add line with:

```
tarout.add(tarname,arcname=os.path.basename(tarname))
```

Note: you also need to `import os`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `\` at the end of `tarname`?

Comment: This won't make much difference.